# Xml output not places where i want

Tags: php, xml-parsing, simplexml

I have a script that checks status of a site and write result in a xml document. Xml is like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <xml>
  <sites>
   <site1>result of site1</site1>
   <site2>result of site2</site2>
   ...
  </sites>
 </xml>
```

Then i have a function that let me get xml content for each site with wordpress shortcodes , like this :

```
<?php
function CheckRemoteService($atts) {
 extract(shortcode_atts(array(
  'name' => 'txt',
 ), $atts));

$xml = simplexml_load_file('my.xml');
echo $xml->sites->$name;

}
add_shortcode('checkmyurl','CheckRemoteService');
?>
```

Shortcodes give me the correct output but all results are placed on same line at top like if are blocked there. I want to insert these results in a table with other data. Is this a xml limit or i have done some mistakes ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function shouldn't `echo` anything, it should `return` it - the code is run while Wordpress is preparing the page, not while it is being output to the browser, so any direct output will simply show at the top of the page before the "real" output begins.

Incidentally, once you're not using echo, it might be a good idea to cast the SimpleXML object explicitly to a string, just to avoid any unexpected behaviour:

```
return (string)$xml->sites->$name;
```